# Add header and footer using JsPDF and template

Tags: jspdf

How can we add header and footer same for all pages through out pdf using jsPDF. And apart from this please let me know that what are all ways to create pdf using jspdf like using HTML content or a string or some HTML template so please help me out on both query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although jsPDF does not have a dedicated header or footer functions, you may use

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text("Header or footer text", x, y);
```

Where x is margin from left of the page and y is from the top.
You may have to position it as per your page dimensions require.

And about your second query, jsPDF has **addHTML** and **addImage** (Older versions of jsPDF) functions to help you generate PDF.

**addHTML** take in raw HTML code as input while **addImage** takes image as input which can be positioned on the PDF page.
**addImage** requires additional libraries such as html2canvas for image generation.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick prompt and if i want to add html content with image is it possible with above statement? and if i want to create PDF using html content is it possible?

Comment: The image content is part of the HTML code, so yeah. You can print the entire document or even pick part of it using jQuery. To answer what you are asking, YEAH. All of it can be done in jsPDF. I've been working with it for few months now.

Comment: Hi  Thanks Gautham and can you please tell me how can i print using html?

Comment: What have you done so far? Providing an insight would let us help you better.
`var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
  pdf.save('web.pdf');
});`
This is the basic set of code to get your entire page to be made into a PDF.